# How to set y-axes limits in countplot?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

df in my program happens to be a dataframe with these columns :

```
df.columns
'''output : Index(['lat', 'lng', 'desc', 'zip', 'title', 'timeStamp', 'twp', 'addr', 'e',
'reason'],
 dtype='object')'''
```

When I execute this piece of code:

```
sns.countplot(x = df['reason'], data=df)
# output is the plot below
```

[image: countplot 1]

but if i slightly tweak my code like this :

```
p = df['reason'].value_counts()
k = pd.DataFrame({'causes':p.index,'freq':p.values})
sns.countplot(x = k['causes'], data = k)
```

[image: countplot 2]

So essentially I just stored the '*reasons*' column values and its frequencies as a series in **p** and then converted them to another dataframe **k** but this new countplot doesn't have the right range of Y-axis for the given values.

My doubts happen to be :

- Can we set of Y-axis in the second countplot in its appropriate limits
- Why the does second countplot differ from the first one when i just separated the specific column i wanted to graph and plotted it separately ?

Comment: You are trying to produce a countplot of already counted values, so each value occurs exactly once. Since the first approach works just fine, why not use it?

Comment: I used the first one itself, i was just curious to know why did the 2 countplots differ